# Where should files used in a saved file template be placed?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, save, itext

I'm publishing a windows form application which allows the user to save a PDF of the information they input. The PDF contains 2 images (logo.png & name.png). I'm currently storing those pictures in my bin>Debug folder.

My question is, if I publish the program, will the PDF still have access to these images or do they need to be placed in another folder in order for the PDF to generate correctly?

```
private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();

    dlg.Filter = "New (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files (*.*|*.*";
    dlg.AddExtension = true;
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf";
    dlg.FilterIndex = 1;

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(dlg.FileName.ToString(), FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();//Open Document to write

        iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("logo.png");
        logo.ScalePercent(45f);
        logo.SetAbsolutePosition(doc.PageSize.Width - 105f - 72f, doc.PageSize.Height - -15f - 216.6f);
        doc.Add(logo);
        iTextSharp.text.Image name = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("name.png");
        name.ScalePercent(95f);
        name.SetAbsolutePosition(doc.PageSize.Width - 500f - 72f, doc.PageSize.Height - -55f - 216.6f);
        doc.Add(name);

        var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 24);
        var headerFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 20);
        var bodyFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 16);
        var fineFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 8);

        //Write pdf content

        doc.Close();//Close document
```

Comment: Could you post code of how you're accessing the pictures?

Comment: Anywhere the user can access on their PC, your application should be able to access.  Unless you see a UAC prompt because you're not local admin, in which case if you store the images under say C:\PDFs, you're going to need to run your application as admin (right click-> Run As Administrator) for it to find it.  Best option is to have the default location of your OpenFileDialog pointing at the users My Documents directory.  This should avoid any security issues.

Comment: Does your program have an installer? Do you want your users to be able to change the images?

Comment: My program doesn't have an installer, which is the problem. I'm using Visual Studio Express, so I have someone else creating the installer for me and I want to make sure it is correct before I send it off.
No, I don't want the user to be able to change the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just add the image as a resource to your project, this will bake it into the DLL/EXE itself. Right-click your project and select Properties and then click on Resources. Click Add Resource and then Add Existing File. Select your image and optionally rename it. Then in your code you can access it using its fully qualified name:

```
var img = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.logo;
var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(img, BaseColor.WHITE);
doc.Add(logo);
```

Replace `WindowsFormsApplication1` with whatever namespace you have setup for your project.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to give the desired results!